# Развернуть Laravel в продакшн на Windows Server 2016 - IIS

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, iis, devops

Использовал docker (laradock) при создании форума на laravel 5.8.

**ФРОНТ**: VUE + VUETIFY (хочу мигрировать на quasar)

**БЭК**: Laravel 5.8 (локальный laradock).

**Авторизация**: в данный момент - JWT (1 час) (надо как-то с сессией на сайте связать)

Исходники форума: https://github.com/kostia7alania/laravel-vue-forum

**Задача: выложить в прод. (LARAVEL 5.8 на WINDOWS SERVER 2016)**

У нас несколько сервисов (сайтов), к которым нужно прикрутить этот форум.

Написаны они на чистом php + ms sql server + c# ( в качестве wsdl, soap).

**Серваки у нас все на IIS 10**. Инфы, как разворачивать продакшн, на такой инфраструктуре нет нашел.
Вот мои наработки -> https://vk.com/topic-125614288_39829274?post=1002
Подскажите, правильно-ли копаю?

p.s. Кто захочет поставить диз, напишите, пожалуйста, причину. Диз за инфраструктуру не принимаю, т.к. сам понимаю, что надо валить с винды, но это махина гос-конторская, стараюсь, долблю, но толку нет (пока).

Laravel 5.5- - пахал на iis без докера. А вот 5.5+ - только через докер, т.к. они там заюзали какую-то функцию линуксовскую.
 А мне как раз нужна версия по-выше, где добавили API.

***Есть идеи как связать сессию laravel с существующим сайтом, написанный на чистом php?***

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос. Похоже, тут несколько вопросов? Если так, сделайте отдельными вопросами (таков формат SO): 1. как поднять структуру 2. как связать сайт и форум.

Comment: тож подумал разделить на 2 вопроса. ))  Но теперь что? на 3 надо? этот закрыть

Comment: Можно отредактировать этот полностью и оставить в нем один вопрос. И завести еще другие. Типа 1. как поднять докер контейнер с laravel на Win Server 2. Как интегрировать IIS 10 с форумом под докер, ну сами разбейте, вы же лучше понимаете. Самую сложную задачу можно решить, если сделать ее декомпозицию. Только не напоритесь на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)